# Rutherford Scattering - Annular Detector in the Far Field

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I have been tasked to find the rate at which scattered electrons will be detected on an annular detector in the far-field.  The exact question I'm working with is:

> Suppose that 1keV electrons, initially incident along the optic axis $\hat{\mathbf{z}}$, scatter from the Coulomb field of a stationary silicon nucleus before being detected by an annular detector centered on the optic axis in the far-field. If the flux of incident electrons is 
>   \begin{equation}
>     |\mathbf{j}_0| = 10^8 \mathring{\text{A}}^{-2} \text{sec$^{-1}$} ,
> \end{equation}
>   and if the inner and outer edges of the annular detector correspond to scattering angles of 50 mrad and 150 mrad, respectively, at what rate will the scattered electrons be detected?

For Coulomb scattering, I know that

\begin{equation}
    \dfrac{d\sigma}{d\Omega} = \dfrac{4m^2}{\hbar^2} \bigg ( \dfrac{Ze^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 } \bigg )^2 \dfrac{1}{|\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}_0|^4}
\end{equation}

Here, $\mathbf{k}_0$ is the incident plane wave vector and $\mathbf{k}$ is the scattered plane wave vector. My question is regarding the $\mathbf{k}$-vectors. I'm not sure how to set them up in terms of the spherical-coordinate $\theta$ (the polar angle). Since we are told the detector is in the far-field, can the small angle approximation, $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ be used here? In this case, $\mathbf{k}_0 = 0$ and $\mathbf{k} = \theta$.

Any help here would be appreciated. I know how to solve the rest of the problem, but I'm unsure on how to work with the $\mathbf{k}$-vectors here.

Comment: dot product of two vectors is product of magnitudes times cos of the angle

Comment: As I read the question, you are wanting to know whether or not use of the small angle approximation is justifiable in this computation.  Aside from being  a question with a yes/no answer without further explanation, I think that this might better be posed to a physicist.  I notice that this question is over a year old, but if anyone is interested in it, perhaps [physics.se] is more likely to get results.

Comment: Related to @XanderHenderson's comment, if this question is about whether using an approximation in solving a mathematical problem yields asymptotically correct answers, perhaps you should explicitly state the purely mathematical problem up-front, leaving the physics motivation in the second half or your post. But if your question is about whether such approximations are accurate in the actual physics experiments, then it is off-topic here. In the latter case, flag it for moderator attention asking to migrate it to Physics SE.